# Is it possible to have apt-cacher-ng retain static versions of certain packages

Tags: apt-cacher-ng

Is there any way designate that apt-cacher should not update versions of certain packages and should retain a static version for a particular period of time?  For example, when I am in an upgrade cycle and I want to upgrade all of my servers to the same kernel version?  I cannot update all hosts at once and I want the package to remain static, rather than being refreshed if a new version is released before I complete the upgrade cycle.

I realize this is essentially mirroring but, I was wondering if anyone can provide any advice as to how I might accomplish this with apt-cacher-ng.

Thanks